# Including property files in a complex project

Tags: java, eclipse, properties, jar, war

I have two eclipse projects.
One of them is a library that contains property files.
Second one is a Dynamic Web Project.

In my library there are few configurable classes, that load their configuration parameters from property files.

```
String path = "Resources/Properties/Main.properties";
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(stream);
```

My dilemma is that when I export my Web project into WAR, dependent library project gets packed into a jar and placed inside my WAR into "WEB-INF/lib" directory, which means that I can't load them as I would usually do.

My ideas are:

1. Copy those property files into my Web Projects, which is very
   painful, because this library is meant to be used in many projects,
   I do not want to have multiple instances of property files scattered
   around projects.
2. Place property files into some system fixed path on the server, still is a bad desigion, makes it harder to deploy this application.

Is there a way to load property files from JAR files, or maybe a way to tell eclipse project to export property files from my library into my Web Project explicitly?
I would appreciate your help and ideas on this matter.

Comment: getResourceAsStream should look inside jars, searching the classpath.  If you unzipped the jar, what directory is the property file living in?

Comment: That would be "META-INF/Resources/Properties/Main.properties". I tried that, but it did not help.

Comment: I dont know how your jar gets created.  you could try change your path to "META-INF/Resources/Properties/Main.properties" or "/META-INF/Resources/Properties/Main.properties".  Or see if you can get it put in a more standard place other than meta-inf.  Also its not java convention to use Capitals for the directories i.e. Resource -> resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine if you load the resource file from classpath.
It goes trough classpath and searches for matching resource.
My problem was classpath resource collision, I had classes with similar package.classname and resources with similar path and filename.
When loading these resources, JVM silently ignores duplicated entities from .jar libraries.
So stay sharp and beware of non-unique entities when composing a complex library structure.